How can I inject an Account Id into a vf page url after redirecting to that page?
We currently have a basic homepage for our experience site which we think it pointless and want to replace with a custom vf page that is an account record page.
If a user logs in through the log in page this is no problem, I have some soql running to grab the account if to use in the redirect url.
However this method does not work if you log in by clicking on the “Log in to Experience as User” on the contact record page in Salesforce as it bypasses the log in page and takes you straight to the custom account record page with no opportunity to provide the account id for the url.
I’ve tried adding some logic into the account vf page’s controller extension in the constructor where if the url has no id it does some soql to get it and then redirects to the same url with the id added, but it appears you can’t redirect from within a constructor.
I then tried using a page action but then discovered the constructor runs first so it errors out before running the action logic.
The only solution I can think of is having a blank home page that does nothing except getting the account id and redirecting to the account vf page.
However this is not ideal because of multiple page loads, is there any other way I can do this? Thanks.

It'd be helpful if you shared your code so that we could see what you've tried so far. It's easier to provide a solution when we can see the problem.

I understand, but unfortunately it is company code that I am not authorised to share. I believe I have been pretty clear in explaining what I have tried (both a redirect in a vf page controller extension's constructor, as well as using a vf page action that calls a method in a controller extension). What I am looking for is more ideas I haven't already tried.

You need not share the literal code, but simply a SSCCE. Having code reduces ambiguity. For example, if I were to answer this question as written, I'd say you just need to have the constructor exit early if there's no account Id, so the action can perform its redirect. But, if I saw some actual code, I might make a different recommendation, perhaps having the action function perform some other logic, possibly skipping the constructor altogether. Any kind of generic code that mimics what you're trying to do could get you a better answer.

You’ve actually answered perfectly. I didn’t consider exiting the constructor early in order to load the action, that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Well, okay, I guess I'll add the answer, then. Glad I could help!

You can have the constructor return early if there's no Account Id. This would allow the action method to work normally without throwing an exception.
